# Is it possible to implement Test Driven Development in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, unit-testing, tdd

I am not a Db guy. I am just curious if there is a possibility to write asserts in Sql so that you can write unit tests for your scripts, for your sprocs etc. and then even implement a Test Driven Development approach to your sessions?

thanks!

Comment: There are 100+ SO questions covering various aspects of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unit+test+sql

Comment: @Ed - those questions are about unit testing generally, not TDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that actually, not directly from SQL throught, but the language you do your application.

Of cause you SQL must be incapsulated in DAL (Data Access Layer) and all data got by Repositories (or other data access classes). You can do unit testing of those classes, that would be running SQL scripts at the end. So, basically you will test your SQL code.

It is simplier to me, than trying to write such tests in SQL. :)

Sometime ago I had thought on that:
http://www.beletsky.net/2010/11/testing-database-and-test-database.html

Comment: Pramod Sadalage ("Refactoring Databases") also recommended this technique and I've seen him do it in Java. As a point of vocab, it's not unit testing at that point (even by Agile's unit testing standards) - I'd call it database testing or integration testing instead.